# RCP e4 buttons group D&D

Tags: drag-and-drop, eclipse-rcp, e4

I want to implement the Drag and Drop that you can do with the buttons group on eclipse (positioned on the toolbar).
[image]

The purpose is allowing to drag them to the sides of the main window. it's possible?