# Eclipse RCP 4 draggable Toolbar

Tags: drag-and-drop, eclipse-rcp, toolbar, e4

Is it possible to create a pure Eclipse RCP 4 application, that uses the nice toolbar from the Eclipse IDE with Drag and Drop functionality?

[image]

Starting with a fresh installation of [Eclipse for RCP 4.5.1](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/mars1), I created a pure e4 [application with sample content](https://github.com/adam-taras/java-sandbox/tree/question-1/eclipse-rcp/e4) using the wizrad.

[image]

It contains two toolbars, but D&D functionality is missing. So what to do next?

Comment: There are already similar questions on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31385417/3536285) and [Eclipse Forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/446194/), but not answered till now. So maybe we get this time an answer :)

Comment: Just add an analog [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34858508/3536285) for the Eclipse 3.x model

Answer (score 2):

There was Drag and Drop functionality in Eclipse 3.x (locking / unlocking toolbar)
But with Eclipse 4.x its not working.

You can see bug : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=409633
There is change in CoolBarToTrimManager.java which is internal class.

> You can add `Draggable tag` for toolbar in application.e4xmi, then it will make the toolbar draggable