# Eclipse RCP 3.x draggable Toolbar

Tags: drag-and-drop, eclipse-rcp, toolbar

In addition to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34855658/3536285), since there are some [issues](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/FAQ#How_do_I_enable_Drag_N_Drop_.28DND.29_of_parts.3F) with Drag and Drop on E4:

> The DND addon is found in the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt plugin`. However it requires the compatibility layer and is not available for native E4AP applications.

### Question

Is it possible to create an old-style **Eclipse 3.x** application, that **runs on** the current **Eclipse 4.5.1** platform and uses the nice toolbar from the Eclipse IDE with Drag and Drop functionality?

[image: Eclipse IDE toolbar]

Starting with a fresh installation of [Eclipse for RCP 4.5.1](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/mars1), I created an eclipse 3.x [application with sample content](https://github.com/adam-taras/java-sandbox/tree/question-2/eclipse-rcp/e3) using the wizrad.

[image: Eclipse RCP 3.x application]

It contains two toolbars, but D&D functionality is missing. So what to do next?

Comment: Hi Adam , were you able to find any solution for this ?